# Reset value on map / transform fucntion failed - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, laravel-8

When i tried to change the value of **id** to **encrypted Id** is using map function and transform function, it get zero value no string value or alpha numeric getting replaced .

but it is mandatory to encrypt all id's for API

Please Help me .

**Function**

```
 function getLatestArticle($profileId)
 {
   $data = Article::wherehas('articleTrans',function($query){
    $query->where('status', ApiConstants::PUBLISHED_STATUS);
   })->with(['articleTrans'=>function($q){
        $q->select('id','article_id','language_id','title','short_description','description','main_image');
        $q->where('status', ApiConstants::PUBLISHED_STATUS);
   }])->latest()->paginate(ApiConstants::D_PAGE_C);

   $data->getCollection()->transform(function ($value) {
    $value->id = encrypt($value->id);
    return $value;
   });
    return $data;
  }
```

**Collection**

```
  "latest_data": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "profile_id": 3,
            "name": "Test",
            "trending": 0,
            "new_arrived": 0,
            "featured": 0,
            "reading_time": null,
            "has_series": 0,
            "status": 0,
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": 1,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2022-03-24T10:27:16.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-03-31T11:41:14.000000Z",
            "created_from": 1,
            "article_trans": {
                "id": 8,
                "article_id": 12,
                "language_id": 1,
                "title": "Test",
                "short_description": "Test",
                "description": "<p><strong>TestTestTestTestTestTestTest&nbsp;</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest</strong></p>",
                "main_image": "1648117636_AXwwVY6JSmNTxmXIiRqGlXiePTl70chCkmMDlehp.jpeg",
                "image_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/admin/article/image/1648117636_AXwwVY6JSmNTxmXIiRqGlXiePTl70chCkmMDlehp.jpeg"
            }
        }
```

Comment: that sounds like a job for a mutator: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: mutator is for seting value before insertion , right? here our case in collection

Comment: you can also use Accessor: to modify the value before get https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: @Hemil as norman said accessor is good  to your problem .since the issue for zero is .you cant assign string to integer type . or you have to return custom array  its diffcult to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not good solution to temporarily modify entity objects only for change API response format.

**Better solution** is using `DTO/Transformer` classes. Good example of transformers implementation is https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/

In this way you can split presentation and model.

Using any packages is optional, you can write simple transformer classes like this:

```
// app/Transformers/ArticleTransformer.php
final class ArticleTransformer
{
    public static function transform(Article $article): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => encrypt($article->id),
            // any fields
        ];

        /*
           // or if you need change only one property
           return array_replace(
              $article->toArray(), // or $article->jsonSerialize()
              [
                  'id' => encrypt($article->id),
              ],
           ); 
        */
    }

    public static function transformCollection(Collection $articles): Collection
    {
        return $collection->map(fn (Article $article): array => self::transform($article));
    }
}
```

Then use this transformer:

```
return [
  'latest_data' => ArticleTransformer::transformCollection($latestArticles),
];
```

**Not very good, but should work:**

Override `jsonSerialize/toArray` method of model, in returning modify your id.